# How to get the displayed text portion in a Flex TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, scroll, textarea

hi want to know the index of the first character displayed in a scrollable TextArea in Flex3 and i need the last character's index too.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selectionBeginIndex and End Index? If they are not returning what you want, try using horizontalScrollPosition which gives you the starting of current scroll position and you can get data from that position.

Comment: I've already tried the methods that you mention but selectionBeginIndex and selectionEndIndex refers to the mouse selection not the current portion of text displayed. verticalScrollPosition and horizontalScrollPosition refers to the position of the text (horizontalScrollPosition: Pixel position in the content area of the leftmost pixel that is currently displayed.)

Maybe i have to do some calculus using verticalScrollPosition and font size but i don't know how.

Anyway thanks for your response